# Impact of WHERE Clause on Table-Valued Function and query performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, set-returning-functions

I have taken over a legacy application that has had many performance issues.
One I found is on a table valued function.

The TVF runs fine as a basic `SELECT`. However, it is incredibly slow when it has a `WHERE` clause on it.

I would have thought that the `WHERE` filter is applied after the TVF query has run?

I don't understand how the `WHERE` clause can have such an impact on performance.

The query is:

```
select * from tvf(@id, @name) where id = @id
```

Comment: Is it a multi-statement table value function or an inline table value function?

Comment: I presume that id is indexed?

Comment: The answer is in the query plan. If you could provide the xml version of the plans you get with the where clause and without the where clause perhaps someone could tell you what is going on.

Comment: Also, if the TVF takes `@id` as a parameter, what is the point of the outer filter?

Comment: The TVF might do something like "and its children", so that the filter reduces the results.

Comment: @Rob Maybe, that's why I'm asking the question, because it could mean fixing the function.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a "bad plan" scenario. Essentially, that when expanded out for that particular set of values, your query is being executed in a way that takes a long time - such as performing many lookups instead of using a wider index.

Expand out the plan for each, and it should become clear. And see if there are certain values that cause your pain, and certain ones that don't.

As a workaround, you could dump the results to a temporary table and then query that with the filter. But still look at the plans and learn what's going on.